# How to resolve ambiguous variables names inherited multiple times?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, objective-c++

so I have a following problem. I have a class which is a subclass of two other classes and they both have positions. Like in this example:

```
struct A
{
    float x, y;
    std::string name;

    void move(float x, float y)
    {
        this->x += x;
        this->y += y;
    }
};

struct B
{
    float x, y;
    int rows, columns;

    void move(float x, float y)
    {
        this->x += x;
        this->y += y;
    }
};

struct C : public A, public B
{
    void move(float x, float y)
    {
        this->x += x; //generates error: "C::x is ambiguous
        this->y += y; //generates error: "C::y is ambiguous
    }
};
```

Later in the code I refer to class C both as an A class and a B class and when I get the position I have a problem. Can I somehow "combine" position variables of both classes? And if not can I change positions of both classes at the same time or do I have to do it like this:

```
void move(float x, float y)
{
    this->x1 += x;
    this->y2 += y;
    this->x1 += x;
    this->y2 += y;  
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are concerned about the duplicated `x` and `y` members in `class C`, you might research about [Virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) (and introduce another base class for position.) Though, I must admit I try to prevent virtual inheritance in my daily work.

Comment: Whilst there are cases when this sort of construct is indeed necessary, it seems like the correct approach would be to not use inheritance to combine `A` and `B` - perhaps both `A` and `B` should inherit from a `moveable` class.

Comment: The "best" solution is to not have to deal with it in the first place. Don't use generic names such as `x` or `y` (unless you're dealing with something like X and Y coordinates), and instead create more descriptive (but still brief) names.

Comment: The comment you left under the accepted answer (and the design you're showing) makes me suspect this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do, actually?

Comment: Do you want to **synchronize** the state of different base classes?

Comment: I followed @Someprogrammerdude 's tip and went around the problem (and yes, I was dealing with x, y coordinates). (wrote this comment so no one more puts his time into trying to answer me when the problem is solved =) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, this can be disambiguated by prefixing the member variable with its class scope:

```
struct C : public A, public B
{
  void move(float x, float y)
  {
    A::x += x;
    A::y += y;
    B::x += x;
    B::y += y;  
  }
};
```

Comment: I think `C::y` should be `B::y`.

Comment: Upvote, because it answers the question. I would avoid that ambiguous variables in first place as pointed out by the comments to the question itself.

Comment: So I have to keep both variables, even if they store the same value?

Comment: @Smile, that is a different problem, a different question :) Without knowing any context, I would say your current design is suspicious. In general you want to avoid the situation you are in now where you are forced to disambiguate, and even worse, store the same information twice. Why do you need to inherit from both `A` and `B`? I would open another question on this subject.